# "While" + Past Simple Vs. Continuous

Tags: grammar

Adele's song says: "It burned while I cried".
For me, I learned that I should use past continuous after **while** or past simple after **when**. so the sentence should be eighter "It burned while I was crying" or "It burned when I cried". The sentence with **when** doesn't really make sense for me so I think they should use the sentence with while but with the past continuous tense. What's the difference in meaning between the sentence in the song and my sentence?

Comment: I wouldn't take grammatical lessons from Adele.

Comment: @Leachoid Is it just slang or completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using past tense like this. It is common and correct to say

> I played with my phone while he watched TV.

There is no grammatical requirement to use a past continuous with while.

Using "past while past" suggests that the two activities occurred at the same time whereas "past while past-continuous" would suggest that the first event started and finished during the time of the other activity.